# Do we know if Delphi's claims are true?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, genealogy

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, Delphi says something along the lines of

> Rodolphus Lestrange telling her when she was young that she wasn't really the offspring of Bellatrix and Rodolphus, but rather that she was the offspring of Bellatrix and Voldemort.

However, when I read it, it didn't seem like fact as much as it seemed like her parents fed her some made up story hoping it would inspire her to one day become some sort of

> powerful wielder of Dark Magic comparable to Grindelwald, Voldemort, etc.

**Is there any proof that the stories she was told are true?**

---

**Note:** I *am* aware that Delphi is a

> Parselmouth, as was Voldemort,

but other wizards and witches have also had this in common, so I'm looking for maybe something more concrete than that, i.e. JKR quotes, book quotes, etc.

Comment: Been wondering this myself after finishing the book; glad someone asked this.

Answer (score 8):

### They probably are

Consider:

- She can

  > speak Parseltongue.

  This is mentioned in the question, but it bears examination, since this is a rather strong piece of evidence. Recall that Lord Voldemort was the last known speaker of Parseltongue:

  > “You can speak Parseltongue, Harry,” said Dumbledore calmly, “because
  >   Lord Voldemort — who is the last remaining descendant of Salazar
  >   Slytherin — can speak Parseltongue.”
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

  All known Parselmouths, beside Herpo the Foul, descended from Salazar Slytherin. And who is to say that Herpo may not have been Slytherin's ancestor. Given the rather small number of magical families in Britain, and Dumbledore's extensive research into Voldemort's past, I think we can trust Dumbledore to know both the nature of Parseltongue, and  who is descended from Slytherin.

  Who would

  > her parents

  be otherwise? Rodolphus? Euphemia Rowle? I think Dumbledore would have known if Rodolphus or the Rowles were descended from Slytherin.

  This *is* a strong piece of evidence.
- The prophecy:

  > DELPHINI: Voldemort will return and the Augurey will sit at his side. Just as it
  >  was prophesized. “When spares are spared, when time is turned, when
  >  unseen children murder their fathers: Then will the Dark Lord return.”
  >
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*

  This fits rather well with the events of the play. Time was turned, certainly.

  > The Dark Lord returned, both in the bad future, in the past, and in the metaphorical sense.

  Spares were spared, clearly, in the case of Cedric Diggory.

  It seems reasonable to suppose that the rest of the prophecy was fulfilled, then: unseen children killing their parents. Admittedly, both:

  > Harry and Albus

  count, but I think Delphini is another strong possibility.

**Is this definitive proof? No.** All this evidence, combined with Delphini's own claims, merely makes her assertions seem *very probable* to me.

Comment: Just as we only ever have Delphi's word that she is the daughter of Voldemort, we only ever have her word that the prophecy is even true. The prophecy is hardly valid evidence.

Comment: I think you should put some lines into spoiler text.

Comment: @A.Darwin - I think I already have a lot!

Comment: @BolteAltamont - That's why I mention how the prophecy was fulfilled as evidence that it is "true" (though this is a tricky concept in *Harry Potter*).

Comment: Hmm, this is a good answer. I'm just realising more and more that I don't understand the prophecy stuff; where'd it come from, what does it mean etc.

Comment: @RedCaio - I actually wonder whether Delphini made the prophecy herself. There's absolutely no indication of that, of course, but Seers do not remember making prophecies, and she does have name very apropos to a Seer.

Comment: Doesn't Dumbledore speak Parseltongue? Not as a descendent of anyone, but as a clever person who taught himself?

Comment: @ThruGog - I believe he [*understands*](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) Parseltongue.

Comment: One thing, if she is child of Bellatrix and Voldemort, Why does she have silver hair? Metamorphmagus?

Comment: @Adamant - Maybe she believes the prophecy, but was force-fed it by Rudolphus and others who might want to mould her into the tool she becomes.

Comment: I think this is good answer, but I agree that everything seems rather paradoxical, which is why the seer theory is good too, but I wonder if perhaps she was created out of a time turner (this instance or another) somehow, because Beatrix was able to conceal her physical appearance at a time where it should of been noticeable...